# Pairing half the sum of the roots with a simple coroot

Tags: lie-algebras, reductive-groups, root-systems

I was calculating something with the root system $A_n$ and I think there might be a more general principle at work.

Here is the example: let $G = \operatorname{GL}_5$, with maximal torus $T$ and maximal parabolic $P = MN$, with Levi subgroup $M = \operatorname{GL}_2 \times \operatorname{GL}_3$ and unipotent radical

$$N = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & & \ast & \ast & \ast \\ & 1 & \ast & \ast  & \ast \\ & & 1 \\ & & & 1 \\ & & & & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Let $\rho$ be half the sum of the roots of $T$ in $N$: $\rho = \frac{1}{2}(3e_1 + 3e_2 - 2e_3 - 2 e_4 - 2e_5)$.  If $v \in X(T) \otimes \mathbb R$, set $\langle \rho, v \rangle = 2 \frac{(\rho,v)}{(v,v)}$, where $(-,-)$ is the usual inner product.  I noticed that if we pair the simple root $e_2-e_3$ defining $P$ with $\rho$, we get something nonzero:

$$\langle \rho,e_2-e_3\rangle = \frac{5}{2}$$

while if we pair any other simple root with $\rho$, we get zero.  $\blacksquare$

**So my question**: let $(V,\Phi)$ be a root system (not necessarily reduced) with base $\Delta$.  Fix $\alpha \in \Delta$, and let

$$\Sigma = \{  \gamma = \sum\limits_{\beta \in \Delta} c_{\beta}\beta \in \Phi^+ : c_{\alpha} \neq 0 \}$$

$$\rho = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{\gamma \in \Sigma} \gamma$$

Identify the coroots as elements of the dual $V^{\ast}$.  Is it the case that for $\beta \in \Delta$:

$$\beta^{\vee}(\rho) = \begin{cases} 0 & \textrm{ if $\beta \neq \alpha$} \\ \textrm{nonzero} & \textrm{ if $\beta = \alpha$} \end{cases}$$?

Comment: This is true because the Weyl vector is the half sum of positive roots and also equal to the sum of fundamental weights. The rho you defined is just the Weyl vector of the whole root system Phi minus the Weyl vector of the maximal parabolic root system corresponding to alpha.

Comment: Wouldn't that make $\rho$ equal to Weyl vector of the root system corresponding to the singleton $\alpha$?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: No, it’s as I said: your rho is the Weyl vector of the whole root system minus the Weyl vector of the maximal parabolic corresponding to alpha (I.e., the root system generated by all simple roots other than alpha).

Comment: The half sum of positive roots with alpha coordinate zero is the Weyl vector of the maximal parabolic I am taking about.

Comment: Say $\Delta = \theta_1 \cup \theta_2$, let $[\theta_i]$ be the root system with base $\theta_i$, and $\rho_i$ half the sum of positive roots in $[\theta_i]$.  What I'm confused about is that we certainly don't have $\rho_{\Delta} = \rho_{\theta_1} + \rho_{\theta_2}$, yet the fundamental weights should add in this manner.

Comment: The fundamental weights don’t add in that manner because the fundamental weights of a sub root system belong to the span of that sub root system. In general the fundamental weights of a sub root system are not even integral weights of the bigger root system.